# Find and Replace Character and Put it to the end of the String in Shell

Tags: shell, sed

I have a lots of string like,

```
DATA/PARAMETER.OUTPUT -40.0000 (Number will be variable)
```

I want to convert this string into,

```
DATA/PARAMETER.OUTTPUT 40.0000- (Even though its 2/3/4/6 digit number).
```

I am trying the below code

```
sed -n 's/-/$-/gp' input.txt > output.txt
```

but not working. its not consider $ as end of line, instead it is replacing - with $-.

I just want to place -40.000 Minus sign to end 40.0000-

Comment: Are you actually trying to remove the string "string" in the first column, or is that commentary?  I don't think your input actually includes the text `(Number will be variable)`, so you should take that commentary out of your sample input.

Comment: DATA/PARAMETER.OUTPUT -40.0000 to DATA/PARAMETER.OUTPUT 40.0000-

Comment: It is not clear how to algorithmically convert `Number will be variable` to `Even though its 2/3/4/6 digit number`.  Either explain that transformation or remove that text from you sample input/output.

Comment: @WilliamPursell, I think OP meant it as a comment.. agree with you that it is better to separate it out

Answer (score 3):

You may use backreference:

```
$ sed 's/-\([0-9].*\)/\1-/' <<< "string DATA/PARAMETER.OUTPUT -40.0000"
string DATA/PARAMETER.OUTPUT 40.0000-
```

To make sure `-` precede a combination of digits an `.` :

```
sed 's/-\([0-9\.]*\)/\1-/' <<< "string DATA/PARAMETER.OUTPUT -40.0000"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk  '{split($NF,a,"-");$NF=a[2]  "-" ;print $0}' filename
```

Example:

```
x="string DATA/PARAMETER.OUTPUT -40.0000" 
echo $x
string DATA/PARAMETER.OUTPUT -40.0000
echo $x |awk  '{split($NF,a,"-");$NF=a[2]  "-" ;print $0}'
string DATA/PARAMETER.OUTPUT  40.0000-
```

To make changes remain in your original file :

```
awk  '{split($NF,a,"-");$NF=a[2]  "-" ;print $0}' filename > filename.tmp && mv filename.tmp filename
```

Comment: I am sorry it didn't. I am sure there would be some difference in the sample text provided by you here and in your real text as it works fine with sample input provided by you.